# HTML table on a UIView in Swift

Tags: html, swift

I am trying to display a table in a UIView that is delivered in html form from a server. It looks like these tables might be slightly different, but they obviously display correctly in a browser.

Is there anyone that can recommend a library that is useful for this?

Thanks for any help.

Edit screenshot of the table cell

[image]

The 'textBlock' gets built up with text, images and hopefully tables. All by appending the attributed text. I can't see a way to switch that label out for a webView.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use that, I think. The display need to be added to a UITableViewCell as a label. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I think I need to use something that will give me an attributedString. The label need to deal with text, lists, images and tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display HTML in iOS it's better to use WKWebView instead of UIView. Then you can use [loadHTMLString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415004-loadhtmlstring) method:

```
webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body><p>Hello!</p></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
```